# OpenCPU not updating png

Tags: opencpu

OpenCPU doesn't update the graph when I call the hist function with a new dataset. It does change sometimes, but it is not reliable I am wondering why this is

METHOD = POST Endpoint : /R/pub/graphics/hist/png
PARAMS :
x, c(1,2,3)

output is a histogram with 1,2,3

then i do

METHOD = POST Endpoint : /R/pub/graphics/hist/png
PARAMS :
x, c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Output is still the histogram of 1,2,3 I refreshed the page and tried to call it again,
Please tell me what is happening here

Additional Note:
I can do a /save as output then use the object returned to view the object it works, but it would be nice if I didn't have to make two REST calls to get the plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a caching problem. Which browser are you using? Do you have `opencpu-cache` installed?

Comment: No i dont have opencpu-cache installed. I installed it now. I will read about the features this has.